# spring-data-solr : BeanCreationException for Repository interface

Tags: spring-data-solr

I am trying to use spring-data-solr (1.4.0) for searching names from Solr. I created a SolrRepository interface as mentioned below but i am getting a BeanCreationException on server startup. Below is the stack trace.

Can someone please suggest what is wrong here?

```js
@Service("searchService")
public class SearchServiceImpl implements SearchService {
 
 @Autowired
 private SolrRepository solrRepository;
```

```css
public interface SolrRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<NameDocument,String> {

 @Query("fullName:*?0* OR nickName:*?0*")
 public List<NameDocument> searchName(String searchString);

}
```

```html
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories("com.test.solr.repository")
public class SolrContext {

 @Bean
 public SolrServer solrServer() throws MalformedURLException {
  return new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
 }

 @Bean
 public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrServer server) throws Exception {
  return new SolrTemplate(server);
 }
}
```

```js
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.test.solr.repository.SolrRepository com.test.search.service.SearchServiceImpl.solrRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrRepository': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:446)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:420)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:155)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
 ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.test.solr.repository.SolrRepository com.test.search.service.SearchServiceImpl.solrRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrRepository': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
 ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrRepository': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:116)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1512)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
 ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:212)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:494)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:379)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:339)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:113)
 ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
 at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
 at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
 at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:57)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:202)
 ... 58 more
```

Comment: What package is your SolrRepository in?

Comment: SolrRepository is in "com.test.solr.repository" package.